# argumentnullexception bitmap save to memorystream

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, memorystream

I'm trying to save my Bitmap to MemoryStream - what wrong in this code? Why it gets me argumentnullexception ??

```
private void insertBarCodesToPDF(Bitmap barcode)
    {

            .......
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            barcode.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp); //<----
            byte [] qwe = ms.ToArray();
            .......

    }
```

**UPD:** StackTrace
System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
in WordTest.FormTestWord.insertBarCodesToPDF(Bitmap barcode)

Comment: You should use using() for streams also try using a different image format and checking barcode var.

Comment: @Sam use using() or not - doesn't matter, the exception always throwing. Barcode var is not null, any ideas?

Comment: could you show what happen before the memory stream?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that your problem is related to the type of image you are trying to save to the MemoryStream as. According to this Code Project article: [Dynamically Generating Icons (safely)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7122/Dynamically-Generating-Icons-safely), some of the ImageFormat types do not have the necessary encoder to allow the Save function to save as that type.

I ran the following to determine which types did and didn't work:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new Bitmap(10, 10);
foreach (ImageFormat format in new ImageFormat[]{
          ImageFormat.Bmp, 
          ImageFormat.Emf, 
          ImageFormat.Exif, 
          ImageFormat.Gif, 
          ImageFormat.Icon, 
          ImageFormat.Jpeg, 
          ImageFormat.MemoryBmp,
          ImageFormat.Png,
          ImageFormat.Tiff, 
          ImageFormat.Wmf}) 
{
  Console.Write("Trying {0}:", format);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  bool success = true;
  try 
  {
    b.Save(ms, format);
  }
  catch (Exception) 
  {
    success = false;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", (success ? "works" : "fails"));
}
```

This gave the results of:

```
Trying Bmp:       works
Trying Emf:       fails
Trying Exif:      fails
Trying Gif:       works
Trying Icon:      fails
Trying Jpeg:      works
Trying MemoryBMP: fails
Trying Png:       works
Trying Tiff:      works
Trying Wmf:       fails
```

There is a [Microsoft KB Article](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q316563) which states that some of the ImageFormat types are read-only.