# Which codec for saving bitmaps to memory fast

Tags: c#, performance, bitmap, image-compression

I'm saving a large amount of bitmaps (screenshots) to memory. Nothing special with the code, it's trivial:

```
var memory = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Since my PC is getting a bit slow, I have run a performance analysis session in Visual Studio and I found out that the `Save()` call takes 37% of "inclusive samples". Another big parts is used when saving to disk, so these 37% are more likely 80% when not saving to disk. (I don't care about saving to disk at the moment. All data is kept in RAM until a hotkey is pressed and I hardly have influence on hard disk speed.)

From my understanding, the `Save()` call has to convert the more or less "raw" data of the bitmap into the compressed PNG file format.

I wonder whether someone has a performance overview of the different image formats with respect to the processing time of the `Save()`method. I'd like to choose the fastest format, even if the file size is larger.

I have tried:

```
ImageFormat.MemoryBmp
```

but that throws an `ArgumentNullException`:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder

I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755819/argumentnullexception-bitmap-save-to-memorystream) that describes that some of the image formats are read-only, which reduces the list a bit.

Comment: As a rough rule-of-thumb, compression is expensive.  So the fastest format for saving images to memory (or disk) will be one that does involve any compression.  Probably ......

Comment: It depends on factors you have not mentioned. If the issue is that you need to take screenshots one after the other as quickly as possible for a limited time period, you may do better by accumulating the screenshots in RAM until your acquisition is finished and then writing to disk at the end. If your disk is very slow relative to your CPU, it may be worth spending time compressing to reduce the volume of disk I/O. If your code is serial and sequential, it may be worth going multi-threaded and having one thread acquire images and the other one save them to disk in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I'm already doing that. A MemoryStream is in RAM, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I was just speaking in general terms. I don't know the specifics of your environment - in fact, I don't think you mentioned a language or OS.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: oh, indeed. I forgot the C# tag. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the non-representative results for taking screenshots of 3 monitors on an Intel i7 CPU, where the application is assigned one core only. I was running a x64 release build and saving to a pre-allocated memory buffer.

```
GIF : ~5.5% CPU load
TIFF: ~4.5% CPU load
PNG : ~4.0% CPU load
JPG : ~2.0% CPU load (note that this is lossy)
BMP : ~1.0% CPU load
```

I also tried integrating [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com/), but since I could not figure out on how to create a `Graphics` object from `MagickImage` in order to save the screenshot, I had to use the constructor that takes the `Bitmap` as argument. This resulted in ~10.0% CPU load for PNG images.

Comment: Someone somewhere in the past did the similar benchmark as you, with the goal of encoding dozens of images in a second with low spec hardware. Thus, the [MJPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)